# How to implement fast forwards or skips in video editing

Tags: video-editor, youtube, visual-effects

I have made a couple of diy and hobby videos in youtube, but without any eye catchy effects.

I would like to implement the effect of fast forwarding with the idea below:

`Suppose I am making a paper plane. First a plain paper is shown, then the paper rotates automatically, and bends in half, fold itself vertically,and so on.`

I have seen a similar effect in the following video in youtube between times 00:01:20 to 00:01:55.

Answer (score 1):

The method used in your example is called "stop motion" and is pretty much the way people create their lego-videos, clay-animations, etc. To do this, you will need to take a picture of the paper, then rotate it very slightly, take another picture, rotate some more, and so on and so forth.

When you took all the pictures, you can import them as an image sequence in After-Effects or premiere and adjust the speed by setting the framerate, something between 10 and 25 should work for these purposes. But behold, this method is very time-expensive - just as a heads up.